# Is it better to have one big or several smaller GPS tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Is it better to have one large MySQL 5.1 MyISAM table with 500M GPS records (and various other meta data) from 100 cars or is it better to have 100 tables with 5M records from each car? There are aprox 40 columns where half is text-based and the other half is number-based.

I assume it is best to have multiple tables as the cars do not share GPS data and thereby there should be no joins between them (but there will be joins to other tables)?

Comment: separating on metadata is an SQL anti pattern.. you may want to read about http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html and I advise to use innodb as storage engine..

Comment: @RaymondNijland - why `innodb`? Is it because `MyISAM` is locking the whole table when inserting/reading and `innodb` only locks the current row?

Comment: InnoDB is much faster vs MyISAM if you configure it correctly that is read this http://www.oracle.com/partners/en/knowledge-zone/mysql-5-5-innodb-myisam-522945.pdf

Answer (score 2):

If all your data is to be stored in one database, it is better to have a single large table rather than a bunch of little tables.

Your programming, indexing, and maintenance are all much easier when you do that. Adding or deleting a car doesn't involve doing data definition, for one thing.

Comment: Indeed +1 @JohnMalli I've missed one detail about the TEXT columns. you may want to vertical partition (read separate TEXT columns from the INT columns in two tables) you really want to do this when you order by or group by to avoid an MyISAM disk based temporary table read about this here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-temporary-tables.html

Comment: @RaymondNijland - it is not text columns but `varchar` columns (less than 50 chars) so I don't think it will create a temp table according to what I can read?

Answer (score 0):

One table. B-tree indexes have O(log(N)) performance. If you have multiple tables you will reduce N but you will multiply it by M where M is the table count. No free lunch.